# How to contain a loop or multiply the loop till a precision is met?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently working on a problem with Wallis algorithm for approximating pi. The problem requires that I call the function Wallis(precision) to return a value of the Wallis pi, and count the number of steps to reach the precision.
The precision is basically pi minus wallis_pi

i have tried while loops which would allow me to enter the precision, but i am unable to get the loop to stop at the required number.

```
def wallis(x):

  counter = 0           
  my_pi = 2.0              
  pi                  
  j= 1.0                 
  while x > abs(pi-my_pi):
       top = (4*(j**2))
       btm = (4*(j**2)-1)
       my_pi *= top/btm
       j += 1
       my_pi = 2 * my_pi
       counter += 1
       print(my_pi)

  return my_pi, counter
```

Comment: precision i.e(0.1 , 0.01 ,0.02 ,etc)

Comment: Simplify the loop condition `while x > abs(pi - my_pi):`

Comment: But my problem is, i need it to return the float value for wallis pi, and the steps it requires to get to that wallis pi with the precision x. if i make the condition absolute, then the return will be integer values

Comment: Why would your variables suddenly become integers if you use `abs`? Read the docs: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/abs

Comment: I simplified the condition, but the return value for wallis(0.2) is (2, 0), i am unsure what the error was, I applied the statement.

Comment: `j` is an int. Make that `1.0`

Comment: my main query is how do i construct the loop such that 2 will multiply after the number of terms required to get the precision of for example: 0.2, is met

Comment: You can put the precision check just before you do the `2 *`

Comment: is there a section that actually covers that? I am very new to coding and i experimenting with projects. I found the equation, but I am unable to check for precision without it going into infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **x** is your precision.

The condition should be -

```
while error > precision:
```

You have written

```
while precision > error:
```

That is not correct.

Try this and just make the precison half of what you actually need to prevent that multiplication by 2 which is what causing the infinite loop.

```
import math
pi = math.pi/2.0  
def wallis(x):
    counter = 0           
    my_pi = 1.0                           
    j = 1.0 
    while abs(pi-my_pi) > x:
        prod = (4.0*(j**2))/(4.0*(j**2) - 1)
        my_pi *= prod
        j += 1.0
        counter += 1

    return my_pi, counter
```

Comment: @Ashwin. Comment on or edit  the answer that you have accepted. Posting redundant answers is not a good practice on SO. Really glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted

Comment: Hi, I was able to get the answer right. I understand i wont input  redundant answers, i just had made corrections inside to get full values for precision. It was a minor change but i understand what you mean. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def wallis(x):
    x = x/2         ## precision is also halved as the pi value and m_pi values are divided by 2 of when pi-m_pi>x
    counter = 0     ## counter after each term has been multiplies within the equation
    my_pi = 1.0     ## wallis pi thats calculated
    hlfpi = pi / 2  ## half of pi used for comparison due to equation
    j = 1.0         ## the value for j that increases by 1 each time

    while abs(hlfpi - my_pi) > x:
        top = (4 * (j ** 2))
        btm = (4 * (j ** 2) - 1)
        prod = float(top) / float(btm)
        my_pi *= prod
        j += 1.0
        counter += 1


    my_pi *= 2
    return my_pi, counter


print(wallis(x))
```

Comment: It worksss!!!!!! i finally fixed the issue. @ashutosh, thank you for your tip, i realised after you divide pi by 2, the inequality is also affected. So i divided the precision as well. So as to get all the 4 terms. Using your method i also figured out how to break the looop. Thank you !!!!!